# Add dict as value to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to add a dict to a dataframe and the appended dict has dicts or list as value.

Example:

```python
abc = {'id': 'niceId', 
       'category': {'sport':'tennis', 
                    'land': 'USA'
                   },
        'date': '2022-04-12T23:33:21+02:00'
       }
```

Now, I want to add this dict to a dataframe. I tried this, but it failed:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(abc, columns = abc.keys())
```

Output:

```
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

I'm thankful for your help.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear in terms of what your expected output is. But assuming you want to create a dataframe where the columns should be *id*, *category*, *date* and *numbers* (just added to show the list case) in which each cell in the *category* column keeps a dictionary and each cell in the *numbers* column keeps a list, you may use from_dict method with transpose:

```
abc = {'id': 'niceId', 
       'category': {'sport':'tennis', 
                    'land': 'USA'
                   },
        'date': '2022-04-12T23:33:21+02:00',
        'numbers': [1,2,3,4,5]
       }
    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(abc, orient="index").T
```

gives you a dataframe as:

|  | id | category | date | numbers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | niceId | {'sport':'tennis','land': 'USA'} | 2022-04-12T23:33:21+02:00 | [1,2,3,4,5] |

So let's say you want to add another item to this dataframe:

```
efg = {'id': 'notniceId', 
       'category': {'sport':'swimming', 
                    'land': 'UK'
                   },
        'date': '2021-04-12T23:33:21+02:00',
        'numbers': [4,5]
       }

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(efg, orient="index").T
pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

gives you a dataframe as:

|  | id | category | date | numbers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | niceId | {'sport':'tennis','land': 'USA'} | 2022-04-12T23:33:21+02:00 | [1,2,3,4,5] |
| 1 | notniceId | {'sport':'swimming','land': 'UK'} | 2021-04-12T23:33:21+02:00 | [4,5] |